# Why does ASN1Object.getEncoded() throw IOException in BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, exception, bouncycastle

[`ASN1Object`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Object.html) (and all classes that inherit it) has a [`getEncoded()`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Object.html#getEncoded()) method that is supposed to return the DER/BER encoding. However it's marked as throwing an IOException.

I expected the encoding to be done in memory and no IO to be performed. Furthermore, this complicates the surrounding code by requiring throws or try catches.

Why is the `throws IOException` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ASN1Object.getEncoded`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Object.html#getEncoded())

```
public byte[] getEncoded()
    throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ASN1OutputStream      aOut = new ASN1OutputStream(bOut);

    aOut.writeObject(this); // This is where the throws happens.

    return bOut.toByteArray();
}
```

[`ASN1OutputStream.writeObject`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1OutputStream.java#L132):

```
public void writeObject(
    ASN1Encodable obj)
    throws IOException
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        obj.toASN1Primitive().encode(this);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IOException("null object detected");
    }
}
```

Unless a child class has overriden `getEncoded`, an `IOException` in this context means one or more of the objects involved were null.